# Error: ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT en visual studio 2017 (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc, visual-studio-2017

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto ASP.NET MVC en visual studio 2017.
Desde el fichero de global.asax.cs, para manejar los errores no controlados intento redirigir a una vista

La función:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["mensaje"] = "Error desconocido. Si el problema persiste contacte con su administrador";
            Response.Redirect(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Rutaraiz"]+"Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
        }
```

Al forzar al programa a entrar en esa función da el siguiente error:
ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT
¿Cómo se debería hacer ésto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema radica en la forma en la que estas construyendo la URL del Response.Redirect.

Ten en cuenta que estás trabajando con ASP.NET MVC, y tu estás construyendo la URL al "estilo" ASP.NET WebForms:

```
http://localhost:44381/Views/Home/Index.cshtml // MAL CONSTRUIDO

http://localhost:44381/Home/Index // BIEN CONSTRUIDO !!!
```

> En el patrón de arquitectura de software ASP.NET MVC, **nunca** se
>   accede **directamente** a la **Vistas** (páginas cshtml). **Siempre**
>   se debe acceder a la **Acción** del Controlador, y está **devolverá**
>   la Vista correspondiente.

Si lo que quieres es redirigir a la Acción `Index()` del Controlador `Home` cuando se ha producido un error, el código sería el siguiente:

```
Response.Redirect(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager
     .AppSettings["Rutaraiz"] + "Home/Index");
```